# How to run a batch file without launching a “command window”?

Tags: python, batch-file, window, command

I don't want to open a command window when I am running an application. I directed the shortcut to .bat file while creating .exe file where the application is python based

Code in .bat file is like this

```
@python\python.exe -m demo.demo %*
```

where demo is my application name (.bat file name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your script with pythonw.exe instead of python.exe and it won't show dos shell.

Comment: Although i runned with pythonw.exe , still i am getting doss shell open while Executing Application

Comment: That is from running bat file. Create a shortcut to pythonw with required parameters and skip bat file.